# Linked Lists Nodes in Assembly (Bomb Lab Phase 6)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I'm struggling to figure out how the nodes are being compared to the inputs. So far I've been able to discern that it requires six integers, which correspond to nodes. Also, the numbers can't be repeated.

I noticed that $rbx was continually getting incremented by 8 and after poking around I was able to find these:

```
0x6042e0 <node1>:       0x87    0x03    0x00 = 135
0x6042f0 <node2>:       0x92    0x02    0x00 = 146
0x604300 <node3>:       0x46    0x02    0x00 = 70
0x604310 <node4>:       0x1c    0x02    0x00 = 28
0x604320 <node5>:       0xf5    0x02    0x00 = 245
0x604330 <node6>:       0xc1    0x03    0x00 = 193
```

I also understand that the code is using a for loop to traverse the linked list. I just can't figure out what type of operation/comparison is being performed.

Here is the assembly:

```
=> 0x00000000004010b0 <+0>:     push   %r13
   0x00000000004010b2 <+2>:     push   %r12
   0x00000000004010b4 <+4>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000004010b5 <+5>:     push   %rbx
   0x00000000004010b6 <+6>:     sub    $0x58,%rsp
   0x00000000004010ba <+10>:    lea    0x30(%rsp),%rsi
   0x00000000004010bf <+15>:    callq  0x4014cb <read_six_numbers>
   0x00000000004010c4 <+20>:    lea    0x30(%rsp),%r12
   0x00000000004010c9 <+25>:    mov    $0x0,%r13d
   0x00000000004010cf <+31>:    mov    %r12,%rbp
   0x00000000004010d2 <+34>:    mov    (%r12),%eax
   0x00000000004010d6 <+38>:    sub    $0x1,%eax
   0x00000000004010d9 <+41>:    cmp    $0x5,%eax
   0x00000000004010dc <+44>:    jbe    0x4010e3 <phase_6+51>
   0x00000000004010de <+46>:    callq  0x401495 <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004010e3 <+51>:    add    $0x1,%r13d
   0x00000000004010e7 <+55>:    cmp    $0x6,%r13d
   0x00000000004010eb <+59>:    je     0x40112a <phase_6+122>
   0x00000000004010ed <+61>:    mov    %r13d,%ebx
   0x00000000004010f0 <+64>:    movslq %ebx,%rax
   0x00000000004010f3 <+67>:    mov    0x30(%rsp,%rax,4),%eax
   0x00000000004010f7 <+71>:    cmp    %eax,0x0(%rbp)
   0x00000000004010fa <+74>:    jne    0x401101 <phase_6+81>
   0x00000000004010fc <+76>:    callq  0x401495 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401101 <+81>:    add    $0x1,%ebx
   0x0000000000401104 <+84>:    cmp    $0x5,%ebx
   0x0000000000401107 <+87>:    jle    0x4010f0 <phase_6+64>
   0x0000000000401109 <+89>:    add    $0x4,%r12
   0x000000000040110d <+93>:    jmp    0x4010cf <phase_6+31>
   0x000000000040110f <+95>:    mov    0x8(%rdx),%rdx
   0x0000000000401113 <+99>:    add    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000401116 <+102>:   cmp    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000401118 <+104>:   jne    0x40110f <phase_6+95>
   0x000000000040111a <+106>:   mov    %rdx,(%rsp,%rsi,2)
   0x000000000040111e <+110>:   add    $0x4,%rsi
   0x0000000000401122 <+114>:   cmp    $0x18,%rsi
   0x0000000000401126 <+118>:   jne    0x40112f <phase_6+127>
   0x0000000000401128 <+120>:   jmp    0x401144 <phase_6+148>
   0x000000000040112a <+122>:   mov    $0x0,%esi
   0x000000000040112f <+127>:   mov    0x30(%rsp,%rsi,1),%ecx
   0x0000000000401133 <+131>:   mov    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000401138 <+136>:   mov    $0x6042e0,%edx
   0x000000000040113d <+141>:   cmp    $0x1,%ecx
   0x0000000000401140 <+144>:   jg     0x40110f <phase_6+95>
   0x0000000000401142 <+146>:   jmp    0x40111a <phase_6+106>
   0x0000000000401144 <+148>:   mov    (%rsp),%rbx
   0x0000000000401148 <+152>:   mov    %rsp,%rax
   0x000000000040114b <+155>:   lea    0x28(%rsp),%rsi
   0x0000000000401150 <+160>:   mov    %rbx,%rcx
   0x0000000000401153 <+163>:   mov    0x8(%rax),%rdx
   0x0000000000401157 <+167>:   mov    %rdx,0x8(%rcx)
   0x000000000040115b <+171>:   add    $0x8,%rax
   0x000000000040115f <+175>:   mov    %rdx,%rcx
   0x0000000000401162 <+178>:   cmp    %rsi,%rax
   0x0000000000401165 <+181>:   jne    0x401153 <phase_6+163>
   0x0000000000401167 <+183>:   movq   $0x0,0x8(%rdx)
   0x000000000040116f <+191>:   mov    $0x5,%ebp
   0x0000000000401174 <+196>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rax
   0x0000000000401178 <+200>:   mov    (%rax),%eax
   0x000000000040117a <+202>:   cmp    %eax,(%rbx)
   0x000000000040117c <+204>:   jge    0x401183 <phase_6+211>
   0x000000000040117e <+206>:   callq  0x401495 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401183 <+211>:   mov    0x8(%rbx),%rbx
   0x0000000000401187 <+215>:   sub    $0x1,%ebp
   0x000000000040118a <+218>:   jne    0x401174 <phase_6+196>
   0x000000000040118c <+220>:   add    $0x58,%rsp
   0x0000000000401190 <+224>:   pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000401191 <+225>:   pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000401192 <+226>:   pop    %r12
   0x0000000000401194 <+228>:   pop    %r13
   0x0000000000401196 <+230>:   retq
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Look at the list-traversing loop to figure out which element of the node is the `next` pointer it's following.  Then you can how they chain together.  It looks like your first code block only printed out 3 bytes from each 16-byte node, so probably those are just data and the pointer might be the high 8 bytes.  Or maybe they have compact relative offsets or array indices...  I didn't want to spoil your fun by reading the asm myself.  (Funny that they left `node1` and so on symbol names in the binary!)

Comment: Is this happening between 163 and 181? Just trying to find a starting point and direction to head toward. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this happening between 163 and 181? Just trying to find a starting point and direction to head toward.

That loop is reading from linearly-incrementing addresses (`add $8, %rax`) but writing to `y=*input++;  x->next = y;  x=y;` or something like that.  That might be constructing a linked list from an array of pointers?  Weird.

Anyway, the key feature of a loop that traverses a linked list is `p = p->next`.  **In asm, look for a load with an addressing mode that involves the destination register**.  (Or sometimes it might load into a different register and then a later `mov` could copy back to the same register.)

e.g. `<+95>: mov 0x8(%rdx),%rdx` looks like part of a tiny loop that goes forward ECX steps in the list.

Then after the loop, it stores the final pointer into an array on the stack?  There's some obfuscated array indexing going on, where `rsi` is incremented with `add $4,%rsi` but used for a qword store with a scale factor of 2 with `mov    %rdx,(%rsp,%rsi,2)`.

I haven't checked on this, but I suspect the code is checking your sequence of integers by "indexing" into the linked list separately for each one, and recording which element it reached after that many steps.  Then recording that in an array of pointers which it will use later.

Since linked lists aren't random-access data structures, indexing with an integer means looping that many times in the pointer-chasing loop.  That would explain the linked-list iteration loop inside a loop that stores pointers into an array.

Yeah, I think that's right.  There's a possible `break` condition inside the outer loop body, but at the bottom of this it there's `mov    $0x6042e0,%edx` which puts a static address (of the first node presumably) into RDX again, and jumps back to the top of the inner loop.